# How to auto-add blank row when referenced column is updated?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Trying to build a auto-updated excel.

Assume there are 2 sheets in total,

Contract Info, Client Reference Sheet

Client reference sheet's column A will contain all Clients Names, and will be constantly updated

Contract Info are the details of dates, products, and etc.

Column A in Contract Info is referenced from Client Reference Sheet.

Is there a way to auto add a new row whenever the referenced column A is updated?

```
**Contract Info Sheet               Client Reference Sheet**
ColumnA    ColumnB   ColumnC         ColumnA
Client A   DateA     ProductA        Client A
Client B   DateB     ProductB        Client B
Client C   DateC     ProductC        Client C
```

If new Client Z is added into client reference sheet, Contract Info Sheet will look like

```
**Contract Info Sheet               Client Reference Sheet**
ColumnA    ColumnB   ColumnC         ColumnA
Client A   DateA     ProductA        Client A
Client B   DateB     ProductB        Client B
Client Z   DateC     ProductC        Client Z
Client C                             Client C
```

I want to make it auto add, so the result I would like is whenever

```
**Contract Info Sheet               Client Reference Sheet**
ColumnA    ColumnB   ColumnC         ColumnA
Client A   DateA     ProductA        Client A
Client B   DateB     ProductB        Client B
Client Z                             Client Z
Client C   DateC     ProductC        Client C
```

### Sorry if I didnt explain clear enough.
[How the Excel should Like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/57oc1.png)

The reference column formula is:
`=IFERROR(VLOOKUP('Reference Sheet'!$A$2:$A$1000, 'Reference Sheet'!$A$1:$B$1000, 1, FALSE), "")`

The turn around I can figure out was coding every client, and add 2 columns in contract Info sheet

```
**Contract Info Sheet                              Client Reference Sheet**
ColumnA    ColumnB   ColumnC   ColumnD   ColumnE   ColumnA   ColumnB
Client A   DateA     ProductA     1       1         Client A    1
Client B   DateB     ProductB     2       2         Client B    2
Client Z   DateC     ProductC     3       ""        Client Z    4
Client C                                  ""        Client C    3
```

[What I can make it look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ESfIK.png)
And for columnD in , IF(D3="Reference Sheet" B3,"Reference Sheet" B3,"")
So at least it can remind me to manually add a show between those two clients?

Comment: `=TOCOL('ContractInfoSheet'!A:A,1)` ? (change the Sheet name to the actual Sheet name).

Comment: If Columns B and C are being manually edited in the Contract Info sheet, I don't think you can do what you're trying to do without exploring VBA.